# How can I change the size of a QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: c++, qt

Nothing I've tried seems to work. setMinimumSize does exactly what I want it to if I switch from a QDoubleSpinBox to a QSpinBox, which leads me to believe this might be a bug in Qt 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my Qt5.1 looks fine when changing the spinbox size. in the layout? did you set layout settings:

```
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored,QSizePolicy::Ignored); ?
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm only having this problem with a QDoubleSpinBox. If I replace the code as-is with a QSpinBox instead, it resizes exactly the way I want it to.

I tried manually setting the size policy to expanding, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Fixed the problem by setting the horizontal sizePolicy to expanding and removing the stretches I had added to the ends of the horizontal layout the spinBox was a part of. That caused the spinbox to expand to take up all the free space available between the labels on each side.

    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

Comment: Great. QSizePolicy is confusing sometimes with streches, I always spend much time on that....

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `QDoubleSpinBox` and `QSpinBox` size policy is the same. But note that their minimum width (or width hint) depends on their min/max value. A default `QDoubleSpinBox` width is very close to `QSpinBox` one, however, if you `QDoubleSpinBox` precision is 10 digits and it's max value is set to `FLT_MAX`, then it's width will become huge as Qt will set it so that the max value will fit without the widegt size being changed.

To fix that, I found two workarounds:

- simply call `setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, sizePolicy().verticalPolicy() ) );` on the `QDoubleSpinBox`.
  However, now the layout management may make it become so small that it's content is not visible anymore. So this solution is not perfect.
- once the `QDoubleSpinBox` is added to a `QLayout`, update the layout (call  `layout->update()`) and then do `spinBox->setMinimumWidth( spinBox->minimumSizeHint().width()/2 );`. Now the `QDoubleSpinBox` may be twice smaller than before. However, large numbers may not be fully visible.